# Remove WWW-Authenticate header

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-authentication

I have a page on my apache which I protect with Basic Auth.

With a JavaScript, I want to check if the browser has any credentials for that page or not, so I want to load the page with a jQuery `ajax` call, hoping for getting either the page or an `401` error.
Unfortunately, the browser always asks me for credentials in the latter case, which I do not want – I just want to know if I needed credentials or not!

I've read that the browser only asks if the `WWW-Authenticate:` header is set, so I want to suppress it or edit it so that the browser doesn't know it.

This is my `.htaccess` (the edit line comes from [coderwall.com](https://coderwall.com/p/ca-2bq/modify-the-www-authenticate-response-header-in-apache)):

```
Authtype Basic
AuthName "abcdef"
AuthUserFile some/folder/at/the/xampp/.htpasswd
Require valid-user

Header always add HelloHello "Blupp"
Header always edit WWW-Authenticate ^Basic SR_Basic
```

This is (partly) what I get with `curl -I <url>`:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Thu, 14 Sep 2017 12:48:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.21
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="abcdef"
Vary: accept-language,accept-charset
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
```

You see, the `WWW-Authenticate` header is not modified, and the `HelloHello` header has not been applied! When I comment out the first 4 lines (the basic auth), I correctly get the `HelloHello: Blupp`.

Using the line `Header always unset WWW-Authenticate` instead brings no change.

How can I modify / suppress the header?

Comment: Try removing `always`

Comment: No change. :-((

Answer (score 2):

I traced that Apache 2.4.25 (as in Debian 9 "stretch") adds the "WWW-Authenticate" header in mod_auth_basic.c (to r->err_headers_out) and afterwards handles the Apache configuration "Header" directive in mod_headers.c which unfortunately operates on a different copy of r->err_headers_out in mod_headers.c:ap_headers_error_filter().

When adding a second do_headers_fixup() to ap_headers_error_filter() as done in ap_headers_output_filter() to operate on r->headers_out also, the problem is gone.

Not sure if Apache considers this problem as a bug or a feature.

Update: The respective issue report at apache.org, including proposed patch, is at:
https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62025

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is the order that Apache modules are loaded and processed.

You can see the modules order running this command:

```
apache2ctl -M
```

You'll see that auth_*_module are loaded before the headers_module so **you cannot add headers or modify existing ones**.

```
Loaded Modules:
...
...
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 auth_digest_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_groupfile_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
...
...
 headers_module (shared)
...
...
```

Viewing the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/hooks.html#hooking-order), the loading order of the modules is determined in the module's own source code.